# How to get View in dbContext with EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm using EF Core and have generated the database with migration (code first). In the meantime I have created a View in DB directly and would like to reverse engineer this views in my dbcontext file. I know I can follow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding?tabs=vs) to get the view but I don't know if this can mess up my existing dbContext class or not.

Is there a recommendation that you only need to use migrations or reverse engineering, or can you mix them depending on the use case you have.

I've always used one or the other, but having the reverse engineering feature in such a case would be great, but I'm not sure if this is a good idea.

Thanks

Comment: You definitely shouldn't be mixing the two things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to not mix these two things. With reverse engineering, you will get a generated DB context class file, but with the code first approach, you are manually writing the context file.

Why do you want to use reverse engineering? If you want to create the entity classes for the views from the DB, you can use it, but in my opinion this is not so comfortable (you should only keep the changes that are related to the views and drop everything else).